# GAE Request Handler path

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am trying to build a simple GAE app and want to store different parts in different python files. For example I would like a URI like:

xxx/appspot.com/books/book/42

My app.yaml

```
application: bookshop
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /books/*
  script: books.app

- url: .*
  script: main.application

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

My books.py file:

```
import webapp2

class BookHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('BookHandler')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*/book', BookHandler)
], debug=True)
```

When I try the URI I get a blank screen instead of the message BookHandler. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your app.yaml should be (note the **books/.*** rather than books/*****)... also, i think it must have been a typo, but it needs to be **main.app** instead of main.application:

```
application: bookshop
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: /books/.*
  script: books.app

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```

Here is what your books.py should look like (I assume you want to use part of the url as a parameter?):

```
import webapp2

class BookHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, bookid):
        self.response.write('BookHandler' + bookid)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                               ('/books/(.*)/book', BookHandler)
                               ], debug=True)
```

**EDIT:** if you want your URL to be /books/book/42 (like you said in your question), just change the handler definition to:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
                                   ('/books/book/(.*)', BookHandler)
                                   ], debug=True)
```

Good luck with your book shop! :)

Answer (score 0):

I would start by separating your routes from your handlers. First create a "routes.py" file and within add the routes for your application.

```
from webapp2 import Route

ROUTES = [
    Route('/books/book/<book_id:\d+>', handler='handlers.books.BooksHandler')
]
```

Note, the change I made here in that the books.py file is now contained within a "handlers" module. Your "books.py" file within this module could look like:

```
import webapp2


class BooksHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self, book_id):
        self.response.write('This is the Book Handler %s' % book_id)
```

The final step is proper configuration of the webapp2 wsgi application and yaml files:

main.py:

```
import webapp2
from routes import ROUTES

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication(ROUTES, debug=True)
```

app.yaml:

```
application: bookshop
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.2"
```